# Best way to add a new column to a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, numpy

I want to add a [image: formula1] vector to a [image: formula2] matrix.

The [image: formula1] vector is currently a list (although easily converted to a 1D Numpy array).

And the [image: formula2] matrix is currently a Numpy array.

I was thinking I could reshape the [image: formula2] matrix to a [image: formula3] matrix and then loop through the last column adding the desired values. However, I wasn't sure how I could reshape a matrix this way (i.e. adding a column). I was also hoping I didn't have to use a for loop.

I looked into using `np.concatenate`, `np.hstack`, and `np.append`. However, I believe I need to create my original matrix as a [image: formula3] matrix with the [image: formula4] column all `None`. This will not work for me because I use this matrix for many calculations before I need to add this last vector to it.

Comment: How can I get Latex code to work here?

Comment: There is [no math markup for stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow).

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-stack-overflow-question)

Comment: @FredrikPihl - I just used URLs to interpret Latex but only one URL actually worked.. I checked all of them and they all give show the correct formula I'd like to display in this question. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [np.column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html#numpy-column-stack):

```
In [100]: v = [1,2,3]

In [101]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [102]: arr
Out[102]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [103]: np.column_stack([arr, v])
Out[103]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  1],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  2],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11,  3]])
```

---

Note, however, that it would be better to allocate the right-sized (and biggest) array needed first, since operations like `np.column_stack` or `np.append` may need to allocate new space for the bigger array and **copy** all the values from `arr` into the new array. That could be slow as well as memory-inefficient. (Why allocate space for two almost identical arrays, when you only need one?)

So instead, you could use

```
arr = np.empty((3, 5))  # the size of the final, biggest array
smallarr = arr[:, :-1]
```

Since `arr[:, :-1]` is a basic slice of `arr`, `smallarr` is a **view** of arr. Modifying `smallarr` will affect `arr` as well.

For example:

```
In [117]: arr = np.empty((3, 5))

In [118]: smallarr = arr[:, :-1]

In [119]: smallarr[...] = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [123]: arr[:, -1] = v

In [124]: arr
Out[124]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   1.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   2.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,   3.]])
```

When assigning to `smallarr` just be sure to use `smallarr[...] = ...` instead of `smallarr = ...` since you want to modify `smallarr` in place, not redirect the variable name to a new object.

You can also modify `smallarr` by using the `out` parameter available in many NumPy functions. In addition to returning the value, the function writes the value to the array specified by the `out` parameter`.

Thus you can do your calculations on `smallarr` and have `arr` already modified and of the right size and all done *in a memory-efficient way.*

Answer (score 1):

If both are numpy arrays of the right shape, it'll work automatically thanks to broadcasting:

```
>>> m, n = 5, 6
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(5)
>>> b = np.random.rand(5, 6)
>>> a + b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (5,6)
>>> a = a.reshape((5, 1))
>>> a + b
array([[ 0.79046654,  0.81610381,  1.6719495 ,  1.46325624,  0.92063256,
         1.06377227],
       [ 1.6789712 ,  1.39644844,  0.94905931,  0.95343555,  1.02492318,
         1.15156054],
       [ 1.37071564,  0.96554418,  1.75242678,  1.33323359,  1.00644693,
         1.08850993],
       [ 1.03423776,  1.03496123,  0.82535266,  0.12488793,  0.45481279,
         0.90367567],
       [ 0.51112569,  0.49737014,  1.01857201,  0.64392256,  0.23526375,
         1.12763083]])
>>>
```

See

- http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: This answer is wrong. What this code is doing is actually adding the `a` column array to every column of `b`. Just print `a` and `b`, and then print `a + b`. Also, the shape of `a + b` is exactly the same as the shape of `b` (`(5, 6)`)