# Concatenation of 2 lists using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]], dtype=int)
b = np.array([[8], [9]], dtype=int)
```

result wanted:

> `alist = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 8], [4, 5, 6, 7, 9]] # as np.array`

I tried:

```
np.concatenate(alist,blist)

np.concatenate((alist,blist))

np.concatenate(alist, blist[0])

for a,b in zip(alist,blist): np.concatenate(a,b)

alist = [*map(np.concatenate, alist, blist)])
```

This got me various error messages I tried to fix by using the next trial. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: Related: [Best way to add a new column to a Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889906/best-way-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing the `axis=1` keyword argument.

```
np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
```

Normally [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) works on axis 0 (going down the array). But in this case you want to concatenate along axis 1 (going across the array). See [the glossary](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/glossary.html) for more information.

Comment: Can you please explain the axis parameter?

Comment: @JohnDifool Added explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using [**`np.hstack`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), this will concatenate the two arrays, but at the *second* axis.

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]], dtype=int)
b = np.array([[8], [9]], dtype=int)
>>> np.hstack((a,b))
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 8],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 9]])
```

Comment: Error message: `all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

Comment: @JohnDifool: well I copied your sample data verbatim (like you can see in the answer). So I guess something is wrong with the data in the question then.

Comment: Working fine for me.

Comment: My bad, I add the alist inside another list on my unit test.